# How do I make hover effect only for images inside div?

Tags: image, html, hover

I want to add a image hover effect on only the div images not the whole html code. How do I do this?

Comment: `div image:hover{ /* magic */ }`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how to ["nest" CSS selectors](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/#nesting).

Here's an example. Is this what you need?

```
<div>
    Image in a div
    <img src="http://baconmockup.com/300/200" />
</div>

div img:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xema2/1/).